# Setting Values for TemplatePart in Custome Control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom control in WPF inheriting from `Control`, the purpose of the control is to display height and width of its parent and the position.

So my control has two `TemplatePart`

```
1. [TemplatePart(Name = "LocationBox", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
2. [TemplatePart(Name = "DimensionBox", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
```

I get these parts in `OnApplyTemplate` method but not sure where should I set the values i.e. Will `ArrangeOverride`/`MeasureOverride` be appropriate method to set the values?

*Note.* I have the code to get the parent element through visual tree helper, so getting position or dimension of parent is not a problem

Comment: Thanks eran otzap. I am not sure what you meant by "but wouldn't it be better to align them properly in your Control Template in order to get the wanted result ". Are you saying I should re-template main control to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the parent element in the `OnApplyTemplate` handler method, then that would be a good place to add whichever handlers you will monitor for the parent control. Then you can update your `CustomControl DependencyProperty`s from those handler methods as and when the relevant properties of the parent are changed. For example:

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    // Get access to parent control here, then
    parentControl.SizeChanged += Parent_SizeChanged;
}

public void Parent_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dimension = e.NewSize;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sheridan thanks for the answer, so if I understand correctly you are saying I should subscribe to some events of parent in OnApplyTemplate and then in those events I update values for my parts (i.e. textblocks).